# how to read stack trace error crash report

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Say I have the following (from TestFlight):

```
0 MyApp 0x000ef881 MyApp + 395393
1 MyApp 0x000efc97 MyApp + 396439
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37dc6539 _sigtramp + 48
3 MyApp 0x00093e51 MyApp + 20049
4 Foundation 0x338fd943 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
5 CoreFoundation 0x36daea63 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
6 CoreFoundation 0x36dae6c9 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
7 CoreFoundation 0x36dad29f __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
8 CoreFoundation 0x36d304dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
9 CoreFoundation 0x36d303a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10 GraphicsServices 0x32a0bfed GSEventRunModal + 156
11 UIKit 0x319e0743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
12 MyApp 0x00091dcf MyApp + 11727
13 MyApp 0x00091d58 MyApp + 11608
```

Here's a longer one:

```
0 MyApp 0x00077881 MyApp + 395393
1 MyApp 0x00077c97 MyApp + 396439
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x37e32539 _sigtramp + 48
3 UIKit 0x31a206e7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 178
4 UIKit 0x31a207a5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 368
5 UIKit 0x31a207a5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 368
6 UIKit 0x31a212df -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 334
7 UIKit 0x31a2118b -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
8 UIKit 0x31ab8d79 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 980
9 UIKit 0x31b0198f -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 4842
10 UIKit 0x31b5b461 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1732
11 UIKit 0x31abeaf1 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 756
12 MyApp 0x00019e73 MyApp + 11891
13 MyApp 0x0002c3c3 MyApp + 86979
14 Foundation 0x3395d50f __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 18
15 CoreFoundation 0x36e12577 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 70
16 CoreFoundation 0x36d9e0cf _CFXNotificationPost + 1406
17 Foundation 0x338d13fb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
18 Foundation 0x338d2c2b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
19 MyApp 0x0002dd69 MyApp + 93545
20 MyApp 0x00023a5b MyApp + 51803
21 MyApp 0x0002425d MyApp + 53853
22 MyApp 0x0001a5c1 MyApp + 13761
23 UIKit 0x31bcdbc7 -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 270
24 UIKit 0x31afaa51 -[UIApplication _callApplicationResumeHandlersForURL:payload:] + 104
25 UIKit 0x31afa30d -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1496
26 UIKit 0x31a1e961 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1080
27 UIKit 0x31a1e3bf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 54
28 UIKit 0x31a1dd2d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5808
29 GraphicsServices 0x32a78e13 PurpleEventCallback + 882
30 CoreFoundation 0x36e1a553 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
31 CoreFoundation 0x36e1a4f5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
32 CoreFoundation 0x36e19343 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
33 CoreFoundation 0x36d9c4dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
34 CoreFoundation 0x36d9c3a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
35 GraphicsServices 0x32a77fed GSEventRunModal + 156
36 UIKit 0x31a4c743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
37 MyApp 0x00019dcf MyApp + 11727
38 MyApp 0x00019d58 MyApp + 11608
```

Now I am pretty confused on what this error is? Any idea? Or maybe tutorial that would help me on how to read this in a more human way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to symbolicate your crash report in TestFlight.  Go the Build Crashes page in TestFlight, you should see an area at the top to drop a zipped dSYM file.  Go into Xcode 4 and run the Organizer, you can do this by going through the `Window > Organizer` menu.  Hit the **Archives** button at the top.  Right click (Control+Left Click) on the build you uploaded to TestFlight and choose **Show in Finder**.  Right-click on the *.xarchive file and choose **Show Package Contents**.  Now go into the **dSYMs** directory and right-click on the **.dSYM** file (e.g. **MyApp.app.dSYM**) and choose **Compress "MyApp.app.dSYM"**.

Now, drag this zipped dSYM file into the section of the TestFlight Build Crashes page that asks for it.  This will upload the file to TestFlight and symbolicate your crash logs for that build.  Sometimes it takes a few minutes, but eventually your crash reports should make a little more sense.

Look for the stack frames in the crash log that mention your app specifically to piece together what happened.  Towards the end you should see a message or symbol you recognize in the crash log.  At the end of this line it should have, if you're lucky, the name of a class file and a line number inside that file that the crash occurred at.  You're looking for the last method run by your code before you start to see the system crashing and reporting errors.  Using the code around at the location specified in the crash report and the error messages the system reported as it crashed, you should hopefully be able to determine the cause or something that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, I thought when I uploading the dSYM it will only parses new incoming crash reports